# Try/Except Block causing ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, try-except

for my coding assignment I am to create a file that will read a csv file, offer different attributes to do analysis over (determined by the column values. I had this code working perfectly, but after I added my first try/except block I started getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/annerussell/Dropbox/Infotec 1040/module 8/csval.py", line 49,
>   in 
>       row1=next(reader, 'end')[0:] ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lw9naofwsu50tfy/grades.csv?dl=0) is a link to a file you can test it with if desired. As you probably guessed this is a class assignment, and I am working on learning python for gradschool anyway so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

---

```
import csv
print('Welcome to CSV Analytics!')

# Get file name and open the file
while True:
  try:
      file_name = input('Enter the name of the file you would like to process: ')
      with open(file_name, "rt") as infile:

# Select the attribute to be analyzed

        reader=csv.reader(infile)
        headers=next(reader)[0:]
        max=len(headers)
  except FileNotFoundError: 
      print('The file you entered could not be found. Please' \
           + ' enter a valid file name, ending in .csv.')
      continue

  except IOError:
      print('The file you selected could not be opened. Please ' \
            + 'enter a valid file name, ending in .csv.')
      continue
  except:
      print('There was an error opening or reading your file. Please ' \
            + 'enter a valid file name, ending in .csv.')
      continue
  else:


      print ('The attributes available to analyse are:')

      for col in range(1, max):
        print(col, headers[col])
      while True:
        try:
          choice=int(input('Please select the number of the attribute you would like to analyze '))
        except:
          print('Please enter the numeric value for the selection you choose.')
          continue
        else:
# Build a dictionary with the requested data
          dict1= {}
          numrows=-1
          row1=[]
          largest_value=0
          key_of_largest_value=0
          while row1 != 'end':
            row1=next(reader, 'end')[0:]
            if row1 !='end':
              numrows += 1
              key=row1[0]
              value=float(row1[choice])
              dict1[key] = value
              if value>largest_value:
                  largest_value=value
                  key_of_largest_value=key
          #    print('dictionary entry ( key, value)', key, value)
          print('Largest ', headers[choice], ' value is ', key_of_largest_value, ' with ', largest_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: After `with` block ends, file is closed. You can't read from it, `reader` will fail.
Probably you didn't notice there is one-space indent for `with`, replace it with common indent so it will be more clear.

Seach for `python context manager` for more deep understanding.

Suggestion here is to factor out all logic from try `else` block to `process_file` function, and call it inside `with` statement.

```
with open(file_name, "rt") as infile:

    # Select the attribute to be analyzed

    reader=csv.reader(infile)
    headers=next(reader)[0:]
    max=len(headers)
    process_file(reader, headers, max)   # <-- like that
```

Answer (score 0):

using `with` you need to move second condition to it block or

replace

```
with open(file_name, "rt") as infile:
```

with

```
isProcessing = True
while isProcessing:
    ....
    infile = open(file_name, "rt")
    ...
    #end of line
    #print('Largest ',....
    infile.close()
    # end the loop
    isProcessing = False
```

Comment: This worked perfectly to solve my error; however, it lead to another issue. Now with my second try/expect clause it keeps looping back after the code executes and asking the user to select an attribute. I tried adding break after my else statement and this didn't help.

Comment: it keep looping because you use `while True:` change it to variable so we can switch it true or false like `while isProcessing:` see updated answer